# number of sample I can select smaller than number of strata

Tags: sampling

I ran into a practical sampling question. I have 24 strata but I can only select 20 stores due to budget/practical constraints. What's the best way to select these 20 stores and how to correct it in the final data analysis?

Comment: If you have more information about the type of analysis you want to do, that could allow us to provide more helpful answers.

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to do cluster sampling; randomly select the regions, then a store in the region.  But as Matt says, you first need to tell us what to do, before we can help you do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to reduce your number of strata.

For example, if you have 24 different geographies (i.e. New York, San Francisco, Washington D.C., ...) then you may want to build strata by North/South/East/West and whether there are over or under 5,000,000 people.  If you currently stratify on multiple variables (i.e. age, sex, income) then consider reducing the number of variables you use or collapsing categories.

The benefits to using strata include being able to come up with point estimates and estimates of uncertainty within each stratum. If you do not have at least two observations within a stratum, you will not be able to estimate the uncertainty within that strata.